# Pass SQL string to oracle stored procedure and get results with execute immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I am trying to pass in a SQL string to a stored procedure and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to return the results. Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P360_RCT_COUNT (sqlString IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlString;
END;
/
```

I am not sure how to accomplish it. With the above, when I execute the SP using the command below, I get an error:

```
EXECUTE P360_RCT_COUNT 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ENTITY_ID),ADDR_COUNTY FROM P360_V_RCT_COUNT GROUP BY ADDR_COUNTY';
```

The error is: ORA-06550: line 1, column 22:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT COUNT(ENTITY_ID),ADDR_COUNTY
>   FROM P360_V_RCT_COUNT GROUP " when expecting one of the following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "SELECT
>   COUNT(DISTINCT ENTITY_ID),ADDR_COUNTY FROM P360_V_RCT_COUNT GROUP " to
>   continue.

Basically I am building a SQL string in a system and need to pass it in to the SP and get the results back to the system. I am relatively new to stored procedures in Oracle.

Comment: How should the result be returned? Consider that the result of a query could be a single column, many columns with different types, ...

Comment: Parentheses aren't optional: `EXECUTE P360_RCT_COUNT('...')`. But that's the least of your worries. If your stored procedure does nothing except execute SQL, what's the point of the stored procedure in the first place? Execute the SQL directly. If you intend to add more processing later, be aware that the ability to execute arbitrary SQL opens you up to injection attacks, aside from dynamic SQL being a pain to deal with in general.

Comment: The SP will return a maximum of 13 columns. The BPM tool that I am using doesn't have the option to do DISTINCT (look at the COUNT column) which is the only reason I am going to need a SP. I am building the SQL on my tool and just need to pass it in to the SP and get the 13 columns resultset back.

Comment: The question here is how do you want that data returned back? An opened cursor? a single OUT parameter with 13 fields? 13 different OUT parameters? ...

Comment: 13 different OUT parameters. Keep in mind this SP will return more than 1 row always.

Comment: still unclear. what is the point of passing a query to a stored procedure, why not execute it directly? when your client component allows to call a stored procedure, it would surely also allow to execute a pass-through query?

Comment: Please watch out for injection attacks when using this sort of generic facility. If someone is able to pass 'DROP EVERYTHING' or similar to your procedure you will have a security problem.

Comment: You are most likely better off with using DBMS_SQL, read https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF

Comment: I understand everything. Now, can someone help me build the SP to return the 13 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to work with a result set is `sys_refcursor`. This can be used quite easily with  JDBC or ODBC.

Your procedure would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P360_RCT_COUNT (
       sqlString IN VARCHAR2
       , p_result_set out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
   open p_result_set for sqlString;
END;
/
```

Obviously the precise details of how you call it will vary according to your client. But in SQL*Plus it would be:

```
var rc refcursor
exec P360_RCT_COUNT( 'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ENTITY_ID),ADDR_COUNTY FROM P360_V_RCT_COUNT GROUP BY ADDR_COUNTY', :rc);
print rc
```

Answer (score 1):

To return lists of values in a `OUT` parameter you need to decide the type(s) to use.

Say, for example, you have to return some `varchar2` and some `date` lists, you could use something like this:

```
create or replace type tabOfVarchar2 is table of varchar2(100);
create or replace type tabOfDates    is table of date;
create or replace procedure testProc(pString        IN     varchar2,
                                     pOutVarchar1      OUT tabOfVarchar2,
                                     pOutVarchar2      OUT tabOfVarchar2,
                                     pOutVarchar3      OUT tabOfVarchar2,
                                     pOutDates         OUT tabOfDates
                                    ) is
begin
    execute immediate pString
    bulk collect into pOutVarchar1, pOutVarchar2, pOutVarchar3, pOutDates;
end;
```

This is way you can test this procedure:

```
declare
    v1   tabOfVarchar2 ;
    v2   tabOfVarchar2;
    v3   tabOfVarchar2;
    d1   tabOfDates    ;
    vSQL varchar2(100)  := 'select ''a'', ''b'', ''c'', sysdate from dual';
begin
    testProc(vSQL, v1, v2, v3, d1);
    --
    for i in v1.first .. v1.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v1(i) || '/' || v2(i) || '/' || v3(i) || '/' || to_char(d1(i), 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
    end loop;
end;
```

which gives:

```
a/b/c/14/04/2017
```

This only works with queries that give exactly a fixed number of columns, of known types.

Comment: I am trying to test this in TOAD same thing above but I get error: ORA-06550: line 5, column 10:
PLS-00201: identifier 'TABOFDATES' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 5, column 10:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 32:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 8, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 86:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 11, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: I added the definition of TABOFDATES just before the procedure; did you run that part?

Comment: Yeah. I added all of it. Where are you testing this out?

Comment: Wait I needed to run all at once. I was able to run from my client but now getting an error: invalid column type: 1111. Do you know what that is?

Comment: Now the question is what type of result does your client expect? I defined my test types, but you should first check what should the type(s) be for your client

Comment: Ok I figured out what my client expects. My clients expects a SYS_REFCURSOR as an OUT. Is there a way with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to return a SYS_REFCURSOR? I am adding the example the client uses on their documentation on my question above.

Comment: This is completely different from what you said before ("13 different OUT parameters"). The answer from APC is the right one.